# Query using Oracle Generic Connectivity returns blank-padded results

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc, varchar

I'm running queries from Oracle across a database link to a SQL Server 2012 instance. All the results are **padded with spaces** out to the maximum length of the field and I can't figure out why. The data type in the SQL Server database is varchar. In `all_tab_columns@mydblink`, Oracle reports the column type as `VARCHAR2`.

Is there some initialization parameter in the ODBC or SQL Server driver that I'm missing?

I'm using Oracle Generic Connectivity (ODBC) and the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on Linux.

**Edit**:

1. Fields are `varchar` on the SQL Server db, according to information_schema.columns.
2. They are not padded. At least, when I run the query `SELECT first_name, len(first_name) from mytable`, I get "John" and "4". Running `SELECT first_name, length(first_name) from mytable` from the Oracle side, I get "John" and "50".

Comment: Did you check records are not padded in the original SQL server table?

Comment: Is the data type in SQL Server `char` or `varchar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whelp. It looks like the data actually *is* blank-padded. The `LEN()` function ignores trailing spaces. Using `cast( first_name  as varbinary(max) )` shows the field has a large number of `0x20` characters at the end.